# Unique Key constraint error not thrown in Snowflake queries

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, unique-constraint

In Postgres, Unique key contraint error is thrown when we try to re-insert record with same combination of unique key.

But in Snowflake, error is not thrown and duplicates are allowed (even after adding ENFORCED keyword in query)

```
create table DUMMY(  ONE integer autoincrement start 1 increment 1, TWO integer NOT NULL, THREE varchar(7) NOT NULL, FOUR varchar(7) NOT NULL  )

ALTER TABLE DUMMY ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUENESS UNIQUE(TWO, THREE) ENFORCED;
```

**DB OUTPUT:**
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Snowflake calls itself a database. But it isn't.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constraints-overview.html

> Snowflake supports defining and maintaining constraints, but does not enforce them, except for NOT NULL constraints, which are always enforced

Comment: Hi! Thanks. Enforcing means throwing error if data affecting the rules (constraints) are tried to insert. So what is the use of having keyword UNIQUE without enforce?

Comment: Beats me. It probably helps the query planner and supports “self documentation”. But you need to enforce it yourself. Happy to be corrected by a snowflake expert.

Comment: Oh! UNIQUE and ENFORCED keyword is only for informative purpose of SQL developers. There is no way to restrict duplicate Unique key combination data in Snowflake like SQL DBs. We have to handle from program manually to check and insert duplicate records. Is my understanding correct? Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you help me with above query

Comment: Hi , one approach in Snowflake is to check the Uniqueness after the data is loaded into the table and if there are any duplicates then you need to delete the rows which are duplicate,

Comment: That seems like the only approach. Either that or ensure duplicates are never loaded.

Comment: @Ragul your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Completely personal opinion:

```
ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUENESS UNIQUE(TWO, THREE) ENFORCED;
```

is a free lunch. You are telling the database, I am going to put stuff in you, and every time I do, run these check for me.

When you scale to really large tables, such checks kill performance, for two reasons. How should the DB optimally do the enforcing. What if it does the same check more than it needs too. In other databases you can turn off the checks and you often do, to get performance on larger transform operations.

Where-as in Snowflake you can/have to manage it. Some people think of this as a curse, I think of it as blessing. You can de-dup your data on the "way in" and then just use it.

Reasons for the DML are it's allows existing scripts to "work". But has the down side if the existing processes rely of exceptions. But to be fair, if you are loading 1B rows, how do you correctly handle 3 dups.

There many ways to de-dup your data, and in our experience we found for large amounts of data types, we used dedicated tables to de-dup our input data based on knowledge of the shape of the data, and the flow of when/where duplicates happened.